# Spring Boot external configuration in Groovy

Tags: groovy, spring-boot

How to get Spring boot to load external properties for Groovy?
Need something similar to java mechanism (application.properties in resources and ConfigBean with @Value annotations)?

When trying to use the same mechanism as with java, I don't know how to annotate the     ConfigBean

```
@Component
public class ConfigBean {
    @Value("${seleniumAddress}")
    private String seleniumAddress; ...
```

and then in     `application.properties`

```
seleniumAddress=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

but with groovy I cannot annotate the field with `@Value("${seleniumAddress}"`
It throws an error complaining about "${}" - this is a special sequence in groovy.
So what mechanism should I use here?

Thank you

Comment: maybe you could elaborate with an (code) example.  i have used both `@Value` and `@ConfigProperties` annotations with POGOs fine in the past.  and difference to the java way, there is none

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use "${}" for Spring placeholders in Groovy you have to make sure it's a String (not a GString): i.e. use '${}' (single quotes).